# Обьясните типизацию

Tags: java

```
class Test{
 List<?> test; // Как это понимать, что это за типизация? Спасибо
}
```

Comment: Речь идет именно о этом "<?>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запись `List<?>` эквивалентна `List<? extends Object>`, поэтому `List<?>` — `List`, хранящий значения любых типов.

Comment: @romashechka это все называется Java Generics - смотрите [примеры здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)